# using RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey Method properly C#

Tags: c#, registry

Summary:

I need to use RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey to query remote registry of HKEY_USERS

Full Explain:

I am currently trying to query registries on remote machines. My code of the RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey Method is below. I know that the
"environmentKey = RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(RegistryHive.CurrentUser, remoteName).OpenSubKey("Environment");"
line from the original example at [registrykey.openremotebasekey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8zha3xws.aspx)
 works. However, i need to query HKEY_USERS which would change the statement to
RegistryKey environmentKey = RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(RegistryHive.Users, remoteName);
and this line does not work.

Any help or code samples would be greatly appreciated! I just need to query the HKEY_USERS registry entries on a remote system. Any method will work for me, my code below is only because its the best method i have found so far to get what i want/need. I am open to change :)

```
        try
        {
            
            // Open HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment 
            // on a remote computer.
           
            string remoteName = host;
            RegistryKey environmentKey = RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(RegistryHive.Users, remoteName);
            foreach (string valueName in environmentKey.GetValueNames())
            {
                string regy = (valueName + environmentKey.GetValue(valueName).ToString());
                Output.AppendText(regy + "\n");
            }

            // Close the registry key.
            environmentKey.Close();
        }
        catch
        {
        }
```

Comment: do you get an exception? is there something more you can give us than "it does not work"?

Comment: @Brian: the issue was that the original code was throwing so many error that id need my own forum just to post them all haha :) It does look like i solved the issue. Please check out my solution code below and feel free to comment. Thank you

Comment: Just checking - you are aware that HKEY_USERS only contains information for users who are currently logged in (on the remote machine), aren't you?

Comment: @ Damien_The_Unbeliever: yes i am aware. its a zeus2 detection tactic to look into the hkey_users registry entries for randomly generated entries. I am using what you see below as a portion of my detection script and only need to run it on active machines :) Thanks for the heads up good sir!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<string> hkey = new List<string>();
        try
        {
            // Open HKEY_USERS
            // on a remote computer.
            string remoteName = host;
            RegistryKey environmentKey = RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(RegistryHive.Users, remoteName);

            foreach (string subKeyName in environmentKey.GetSubKeyNames())
            {
                hkey.Add(subKeyName);
            }

            // Close the registry key.
            environmentKey.Close();
        }
        catch
        {
        }
```

Comment: `RegistryKey environmentKey = RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(RegistryHive.Users, remoteName);`

should be wrapped in a `using`